# How to find out where bad login attempt is coming from for a Domain Account (Windows 2008 Server R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, user-accounts

I have an account that keeps getting locked out (a domain account).

I can see when the last bad login occurred and the bad login count = 5. What I want to determine is the IP address of the machine that is responsible for the bad logins.

How can I find this out?

Comment: A useful tool to determine which DC's event logs to check for the bad password and/or account lockout events in question.
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/48758-trace-the-source-of-a-bad-password-and-account-lockout-in-ad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, auditing of logon failures needs to be enabled. As a matter of practice, I've always put it in an enforced default domain policy, but you should at least have it applied to your domain controllers. The entry is called Audit Account Logon Events, and it only defaults to logging Success for some reason. Info on this setting is available from Microsoft [on Technet here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787176%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Once that is enabled, the security logs of the Domain Controller processing the login should contain the necessary information. Specifically, check for Failure Audits of Logon/Logoff Events. The username should be a column called User that you can sort/filter by to ease the search.

Comment: Logon event auditing needs to be enabled first, which isn't by default.

Comment: You're correct, come to think of it. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: +1, Example of the logged event: http://www.netid.washington.edu/images/675.jpg

Comment: I have a Server 2008R2 box as well and looking in my local policy the success and failure are both checked.  Yet when I logoff my DC and then try to logon with a bad password, or an account that does not exist, then logon with my admin account...  I check the security log and NO 675 events are there.

Comment: Just went through this process and found that these events only seem to be logged to the DC with the PDC fsmo role assigned. Be aware if you are in an environment with multiple domain controllers you should be looking at the event log of the PDC. You can find that host with this command: `netdom query fsmo`